# Changes to flask template not showing on deployed website

Tags: html, templates, nginx, flask

I have deployed a website built with flask and nginx/gunicorn to an AWS EC2 instance but any changes I try to make to base.html template will not show on the site.  The base.html has my header and footer.  I created an extra html page (just for testing) that has the same footer content as base and those changes are being shown when I trigger that route, but routes that render html which extends base will not show the same changes.

here is the base.html structure I'm using for flask - anything I try to change on this document in the head and footer doesn't seem to show - but it is 100% being rendered by the website because the header and footer do not exist anywhere else.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ... imports etc. ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            ... header content ...
        </header>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        <footer class="footer">
            ... footer content ...
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have cleared browser history, I've tried disabling sendfile in nginx.conf, I've visited the site from a device that has never been to the site and my base.html changes never show.  nginx reload/restart doesn't show the changes to base.html, from what I can tell gunicorn does not do caching, and running the site locally has no issue showing changes I make.  I have successfully made other changes to the site like changing the favicon around.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the code below to your app or your **init** file

```
 app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```

Reboot your server, start Gunicorn, restart Supervisor and Nginx